# How do I use LAPACK in a Visual Studio 2008 project using Armadillo

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors, runtime-error, lapack, armadillo

I'm trying to use an open source library http://arma.sourceforge.net for linear algebra calculations. Some of the functions in Armadillo like [pinv](http://arma.sourceforge.net/reference.html#pinv) use LAPACK. I've written a very simple piece of code to use Armadillo to calculate pinv, but it produces a runtime error. This is probably because I do not have LAPACK linker flags in the sln file.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "armadillo"

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {

 mat A = rand<mat>(4,5);
 mat pinverse = pinv(A); 
 A.print("A=");
 return 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, do you have LAPACK library? If not, get one (there's a number of implementations to choose). Otherwise, check that library's documentation or readme. There's nothing specific to Visual C++ here.

Usually all that's needed is:
add "lapack.lib" to linker input (in project settings).

Comment: I updated answer with obvious lib file, otherwise - can't help, there must be something unusual about your situation. Try clean installation on a different PC if you can.

Comment: The VS 2008 sln i'm trying to compile is here : http://sites.google.com/site/icemancode/file-cabinet/pseudoInverseMat.rar?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 0):

In order to use LAPACK, assuming you are linking the libs to your project, you also need to uncomment #define ARMA_USE_LAPACK in Armadillo's config.hpp. Same thing goes for BLAS.